# Convert set date to user's local time automatically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am creating an application where I have a pretty big set of dates and times, and I need to display these in the user's local time and date. All set dates and times are in BST; so for example **08-24-2014 16:00 BST** = **08-24-2014 11:00 EST**. Now, before coming here I spent good 3-4 hours looking for an answer but if anything, I got more confused. **Is there any way, to convert a set of BST dates and times to the user's local settings automatically without them setting the time zone etc?**

p.s.: I have two ideas in mind but I don't know if they would work nor how to execute them.

1) Get and change the BST date and time and convert it to a unit of measurement; get and change the user's local date and time and covert it to the same unit of measurement as above, calculate the difference in the new measurement, and convert that to the user's local time.

2) Use GeoLocation to find the user's date and time/ time zone and; convert the BST to whatever the GeoLocation spits out.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the users machine timezone in javascript:

```
var currentDate = new Date();
var currentTimeZoneOffsetInHours = currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;
```

see documentation here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

having the offset you can add it to your values

Comment: I am struggling to get the concept completely. I understand that it returns the difference in minutes between the user's machine time and the UTC, but what about the UTC to BST? Is there such thing? If there is, I assume I have to add the calculation manually? Thank you for the guidance :)

Comment: are you talking about "British Summer Time"? what about the dates and their times that are in winter? are these also represented by british summer time? would this mean to get them in local british time you would have to substract one hour from all winter dates?

Comment: All dates and times are always posted in BST regardless if it's winter or not

Comment: this means: if a user is in the UK all winter dates will need to get one hour subtracted. for other timezones winter dates will additionally have to get the UTC offset and their daylight savings time added. correct?

Answer (score 0):

there is a javascript library [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com) which allows you to query daylight saving values for specific dates and timezones.

1. because all your dates are in british summer time. first query if a date is in british winter time with `isDSTShifted()`. and `subtract()` an hour.
2. convert the date to another timezone